# Induced isomorphism of cohomology group implies induced isomorphism of cohomology with any coefficient

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

> Let $f,g:C_* \rightarrow D_*$ be maps of nonnegative chains of free abelian group. Suppose that $f^*=g^*: H^*(C,\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^*(D,\mathbb{Z})$. Prove that $f$ induces isomorphism of cohomology group with coefficient in any abelian group, i.e. $f^*:H^*(C,G)\rightarrow H^*(D,G)$ is isomorphism.
>
> Is it true that it induces the same isomorphisms $f^*=g^*:H^*(C,G)\rightarrow H^*(D,G)$ for any abelian group $G$?

I thought that first statement implies from Universal Coefficient Theorem, but I made stupid mistake... Could anyone help me how to prove this statement? Maybe I can use UCT, but in more subtle way?

I have also problem to decide if for two the same induced isomorphism of cohomology with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients have to induce the same isomorphism in any coefficient. I think that it isn't true (and probably it is the case that in UTC this sequence don't splits naturally), but I can't give a counterexample or prove.

Comment: I think you have two different statements confused here.  It's certainly not true that $f^*$ must be an isomorphism (nothing in your assumptions prevents having $f=g=0$).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782321/isomorphism-on-cohomology-implies-isomorphism-on-homology answers what might be your intended question.